# Variable outside function

Tags: android, kotlin

Using variable outside lambda "rm". I've searched around for a while and no solution seems to be correct.
Most are suggestions to make it global (Which doesn't work)
How do I get the last print have data?

```
var rm : String? = null;
        Fuel.get("http://192.168.56.1:8080/getimage").response { request, response, result ->
            val (bytes, error) = result
            when (result) {
                is com.github.kittinunf.result.Result.Failure -> {
                    val ex = result.getException()
                    println(ex)
                }
                is com.github.kittinunf.result.Result.Success -> {
                    if (bytes != null) {
                        val e = JsonParser().parse(String(bytes))
                        val obj = e.asJsonObject
                        val rm = obj.get("url").asString
                        println(rm) //Has data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        println(rm) //Doesnt have data
    }
```

Comment: You do not assign any value to your outside rm variable. You create new rm val and assign value to it, so it prints something into console.

Comment: That's not correct, he's just calling another function. Not taking the variable out of scope

Comment: You are shadowing variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

redefined rm in

> val rm = obj.get("url").asString

remove "val"